# How correctly install jquery and bootstrap with bower? (need best practices)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bower

I used bower to add twitter bootstrap and jquery to my Laravel project.

I configured bower to add packages to "public/components" directory.

But it installs full packages, there are not only main files of bootstrap and jquery. But also sources, files aka README or LICENSE , less files etc

I don't want to have all this in my public folder .

If i configure bower to install outside of public/ folder then browser can not download files.

What are best practices for such configuration?
Is this normal to have full packages in public folder?

Answer (score 1):

Use a task runner such as Grunt, Webpack, or Gulp to read the required files from your bower_components directory and build an asset that it places in your public directory. These are fairly robust options.